# In AWK, why does a nonexistent field like $(NF+1) not equal zero?

Tags: awk

When using AWK, I'm struggling to understand why a nonexistent field (a field after `$NF`) does not compare equal to numeric zero.

In the example below, the input line has two fields, so according to the spec `$3` should be an "uninitialized value" and compare equal to 0. In other words, `$3 == 0` should return true, but as you can see below it returns false:

```
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{ print($3 == 0 ? "t" : "f") }'
f
```

Both "One True AWK" (version 20121220) and GNU AWK (version 4.2.1) behave the same way. Here's the GNU AWK output:

```
$ echo '1 2' | gawk '{ print($3 == 0 ? "t" : "f") }'
f
```

According to the [POSIX AWK spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), nonexistent fields like `$3` should be uninitialized values:

> References to nonexistent fields (that is, fields after $NF), shall evaluate to the uninitialized value.

Additionally, comparisons like `==` should be made numerically if one operand is numeric and the other is an uninitialized value:

> Comparisons (with the '<', "<=", "!=", "==", '>', and ">=" operators) shall be made numerically if both operands are numeric, if one is numeric and the other has a string value that is a numeric string, or if one is numeric and the other has the uninitialized value. Otherwise, operands shall be converted to strings as required...

And finally, an uninitialized value's "numeric value" should be zero:

> An uninitialized value shall have both a numeric value of zero and a string value of the empty string.

Contrast this to an uninitialized variable, which *does* compare equal to zero:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print(x == 0 ? "t" : "f") }'
t
```

So in our first example, `$3` should be an uninitialized value, `==` should compare it numerically, and its numeric value should be zero. Hence it seems to me that `$3 == 0 ? "t" : "f"` should output `t` instead of `f`.

Can anyone help my understand why it doesn't, or help me see how I'm misreading the spec?

Comment: I dunno why the behavior is different.. but you could workaround by forcing conversion.. `$3+0`, `x+0`, etc for uniform behavior..

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that works -- however, the context is I'm actually implementing an AWK interpreter (in Go) so really need to understand the whys and hows of the spec.

Comment: very likely, `$(NF+x)` will have **only** empty string as value. if you check `awk 'BEGIN{print x==$10?"t":"f"}'` -> True, then `""==$10` -> True, but `0==$10` -> False. My guess is, the doc for this point is not 100% correct. It is an empty string for non-existing field instead of uninit-value.

Comment: Fields are probably handled internally as an array. If that's the case, an [uninitialized subscript](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Uninitialized-Subscripts.html) is treated as a null string. As suggested, your code works if `$3++` is used in your code.

Comment: I agree that, according to the spec, `$3 == 0` should be true. However, the question becomes, is the existing nonconforming behavior widespread enough that strictly following the spec will violate a *de facto* standard? While a specification can't really be "wrong" in theory, it can be wrong in practice to adhere to it. If you choose to stick to the spec, at least document your decision clearly. It would probably be worth reaching out to the maintainers to the other implementations for their opinion on the matter.

Comment: From [gnu.org site](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html#Fields): *If you try to reference a field beyond the last one (such as $8 when the record has only seven fields), you get the empty string. (If used in a numeric operation, you get zero.) *

Comment: @LuisMuñoz: Comparing with a number isn't a numeric operation for you? ... if not, that is certainly at odds with Posix, and requesting Posix-conformance with the `--posix` command-line option does not change it.

Comment: @rici I was just citing the GNU manual. All in all, a comparison operation should not change operand values so I personally wouldn't expect the field value to change due to a comparison operation.

Comment: @Luis: In Awk, no operation changes an operand value. Rather, certain operands have two values, because they can be both numbers and strings. Operands with two values are the unitialized value, and any value originating with user input which is syntactically a number (possibly surrounded with whitespace). Operators *select* one of the two possible values: arithmetic operators select the numeric value, if there is one; string operators select the string value, if there is one. Comparison operators are supposed to select the value of the type which matches the other operand.

Comment: @rici this is an interesting topic indeed. A field is user input and should not be changed unless an explicit operation is performed. Changing it to 0 to perform the best fitted comparison would be incorrect for me. In other words, a comparison must be a non-invasive operation.

Comment: @Luis: For another example, if the input is `1.0`, do you consider `$1==1` to be true or false? Gawk and Posix both say true, but that's clearly a *change* to the user input, considering the input to be a string.

Comment: @rici user input is not changed during the operation, still prints  `1.0` after the comparison. @kvantour answer settles the issue it seems.

Comment: @Luis: user input is not modified by considering an empty field to be equal to 0 either. After the comparison, the empty field is still empty.

Comment: @BenHoyt I'm about to start learning "Go" with a view to using it in earnest in a few weeks for GUI development. I have some experience using awk so if you'd like any code review or discussion in future maybe we can help each other out, time permitting.

Comment: Happy to help, @EdMorton. Just ping me using the website/email in my SO profile.

Comment: FYI I've opened a ticket (#193457 but no-one else can see it AFAIK) with the Open Group to try to get the POSIX standard fixed.

Comment: And we now have a defect report at the Austin Group (which I guess is the org that provides the content for the Open Group) based on my Open Group ticket and that Austin Group one everyone CAN see - http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1198.

Comment: and see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2018-08/msg00000.html for what is (or is not) happening with gawk wrt the remaining related issue of POSIX conformance for handling unpopulated fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interesting passage in ***The AWK Programming Language*** by *Alfred V. Aho, Brian W. Kernighan and Peter J. Weinberger* (1988) ([book here](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)):

> Uninitialized variables are created with the numeric value 0 and the string
>   value `""`. **Nonexistent fields and fields that are explicitly null have only the string value `""`; they are not numeric**, but when coerced to numbers they acquire the numeric value 0.
>
> **<sup>source: [The AWK Programming Language, section 2.2, p 45](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)</sup>**

Furthermore:

> Uninitialized variables have the numeric value `0` and the string value `""`. Accordingly,
>   if `x` is uninitialized,
>
> ```
> if (x) ...
> ```
>
> is false, and
>
> ```
> if (!x) ...
> if (x == 0) ...
> if (x == "") ...
> ```
>
> are all true. But note that
>
> ```
> if (x == "0") ...
> ```
>
> is false.
>
> The type of a field is determined by context when possible; for example, `$1++`
>   implies that `$1` must be coerced to numeric if necessary, and
>   `$1 = $1 "," $2`
>   implies that `$1` and `$2` will be coerced to strings if necessary.
>
> In contexts where types cannot be reliably determined, e.g.,
>
> ```
> if {$1 == $2) ...
> ```
>
> the type of each field is determined on input. **All fields are strings**; in addition, *each field that contains only a number is **also** considered numeric*. Fields that are explicitly null have the string value `""`; they are **not numeric**. **Nonexistent
>   fields (i.e., fields past `NF`) and `$0` for blank lines are treated this way too.**
>
> As it is for fields, so it is for array elements created by `split`.
>
> **<sup>source: [The AWK Programming Language, Appendix A, *Initialization, comparison, and type coercion*, p 192](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)</sup>**

In my opinion, these lines explain nicely the observed behavior and it seems that most programs follow this too.

---

On top of that, in addendum to the post of [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638061/8344060):

When investigating the source code of GNU Awk 4.2.1, I found that:

- Uninitialized variables are assigned the `Node` named `Nnull_string` which has the flags :

  ```
  main.c: Nnull_string->flags = (MALLOC|STRCUR|STRING|NUMCUR|NUMBER);
  ```
- Nonexistent fields are assigned the Node named `Null_field` which is a redefined `Nnull_string` as:

  ```
  field.c: *Null_field = *Nnull_string;
  field.c: Null_field->valref = 1;
  field.c: Null_field->flags = (STRCUR|STRING|NULL_FIELD); /* do not set MALLOC */
  ```

Where the fields have the values (from `awk.h`):

```
#       define  STRING  0x0002       /* assigned as string */
#       define  STRCUR  0x0004       /* string value is current */
#       define  NUMCUR  0x0008       /* numeric value is current */
#       define  NUMBER  0x0010       /* assigned as number */
#       define  NULL_FIELD 0x2000    /* this is the null field */
```

The comparison function `int cmp_nodes(NODE *t1, NODE *t2, bool use_strcmp)` defined in `eval.c`, just checks if the `NUMBER` flag is set in both `t1` and `t2`:

```
if ((t1->flags & NUMBER) != 0 && (t2->flags & NUMBER) != 0)
    return cmp_numbers(t1, t2);
```

As the `Null_field` does not have the number field, it will just assume that it represents a string. This all seems to be in line with what the book cites!

Furthermore, from `awk.h`:

```
* STRING and NUMBER are mutually exclusive, except for the special
* case of an uninitialized value, represented internally by
* Nnull_string. They represent the type of a value as assigned.
* Nnull_string has both STRING and NUMBER attributes, but all other
* scalar values should have precisely one of these bits set.
*
* STRCUR and NUMCUR are not mutually exclusive. They represent that
* the particular type of value is up to date.  For example,
*
*   a = 5       # NUMBER | NUMCUR
*   b = a ""    # Adds STRCUR to a, since a string value
*               # is now available. But the type hasn't changed!
*
*   a = "42"    # STRING | STRCUR
*   b = a + 0   # Adds NUMCUR to a, since numeric value
*               # is now available. But the type hasn't changed!
```

Comment: The comment preceding those `define`s is possibly more clear than the comments in the lines you cite (many of which are actually just noise w.r.t. this question. :-) )

Comment: @rici agreed, removed some stuff and found a bit more information in _"The AWK Programming Language"_ which describes the comment in `awk.h` you were referring too.

Comment: `As it is for fields, so it is for array elements created by split. ` is IMHO misleading since split() cannot create elements that don't exist and there's no way to test an array elements value without causing it to exist so if you do `split("x y",a); if (a[3] == 0) ...` then `a[3]` didn't exist before the `if` but by referencing it in the `if` then `a[3]` will be created with the value `zero-or-null` and the comparison with `0` will succeed. So I'm not sure what they were trying to say with that sentence - array elements simply always have the type numeric-string just like scalar variables.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, you're reading the Posix spec correctly. The Posix spec is based on *The AWK Programming Language* (which is included as an [informative reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/frontmatter/refdocs.html)) but seeks to make certain aspects of the language more precise. In particular, previous practices for dealing with string values and number values lead to some curious consequences, some of which are noted in the [Rationale section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_18) of the Posix utility description. The opinion of the Posix authors is that "[t]he behavior of historical implementations was seen as too unintuitive and unpredictable," and looking at one of the examples, it is hard to disagree:

```
$ seq 1 4 | nawk '{
>     a = "+2"
>     b = 2
>     if (NR % 2)
>         c = a + b
>     if (a == b)
>         print "numeric comparison"
>     else
>         print "string comparison"
> }
> '
numeric comparison
string comparison
numeric comparison
string comparison
```

The precise handling of empty and unspecified field values is one of the differences between the Posix spec and the awk language defined by *The Awk Programming Language*. So in the end, you will have to decide which specification you consider definitive.

As you note, Posix says clearly that: ([Variables and special values](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_03))

> References to nonexistent fields (that is, fields after $NF), shall evaluate to the uninitialized value.…

In fact, it's not just invalid fields which receive this treatment. Although empty strings are not "numeric strings" as defined by Posix [Note 1], an exception is made for empty fields (which are possible if you explicitly set the field separator):

> Each field variable shall have a string value or an uninitialized value when created. Field variables shall have the uninitialized value when created from `$0` using **FS** and the variable does not contain any characters.

Comparison operators are numeric if one argument is a number and the other is a number, a "numeric string" or an uninitialized value: ([Expressions in awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02), emphasis added):

> Comparisons (with the `'<'`, `"<="`, `"!="`, `"=="`, `'>'`, and `">="` operators) shall be made numerically if both operands are numeric, if one is numeric and the other has a string value that is a numeric string, or if **one is numeric and the other has the uninitialized value**. Otherwise, operands shall be converted to strings as required and a string comparison shall be made…

However, that is not the Gnu awk implementation, and it is apparently not the implementation in many other awks. Common implementations:

- Treat empty and invalid fields as the empty string (which is not a numeric string) rather than an unitialized value; and
- Compare two "numeric strings" using numeric comparison, not string comparison.

I can't find an archive of an awk mailing list that goes back far enough in time, and the source history on Savannah only goes back to 2006 or so, but the [Changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/ChangeLog.0) includes the following entry from 1997:

> Sun Jan 19 23:37:03 1997  Arnold D. Robbins
>
> ```
> * field.c (get_field): Add new var that is like Nnull_string but
>   does not have numeric attributes, so that new fields are strings.
> ```

And the code still reflects that decision. (`Nnull_string` is gawk's uninitialized value. The variable referred to is now the global `Null_field`.)

Interestingly, in a `BEGIN` rule, gawk (correctly) treats `$0` as uninitialized rather than empty:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print $0 == 0, $1 == 0}'
1 0
```

---

#### Notes

1. A "numeric string" is a string *originating from user input* whose form is that of a number. This does not include quoted literals in an awk program; `"1"` is a string, not a numeric string. The possible origins of a numeric string are listed in the "Expressions in awk" section referenced above; they include fields, environment variables and command-line options, and the attribute is preserved by assignment.

   Having the form of a number is also defined in that section, where implementations are given two options:

   - Use the equivalent of strtod, with the additional constraint that the number parsed must consist of at least one character and that all trailing characters be whitespace;
   - Use the lexical definition of NUMBER from the awk grammar.

   Neither of these possibilities allows an empty string to be a numeric string.

Comment: See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1198 and https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2018-08/msg00000.html for how the issues are being resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard seems to be more confusing than necessary when discussing this but look at this statement in the table in [the "Expressions in awk" part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02):

```
Syntax |      Name       | Type of Result | Associativity
$expr  | Field reference |    String      |     N/A
```

so the type of `$<whatever>` by default is String. Now lets see what that section says about how it might become Numeric-String:

```
A string value shall be considered a numeric string if it comes from one of the following:

    Field variables

    <other N/A stuff - Ed.>

and an implementation-dependent condition corresponding to either case (a) or (b) below is met.

    a) After the equivalent of the following calls to functions defined by the ISO C standard, string_value_end would differ from string_value, and any characters before the terminating null character in string_value_end would be <blank> characters:

    char *string_value_end;
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "");
    numeric_value = strtod (string_value, &string_value_end);
```

When passed a NULL string strtod() will return 0 but string_value_end would NOT differ from string_value so the above test will not recognize NULL as a numeric string.

```
    b) After all the following conversions have been applied, the resulting string would lexically be recognized as a NUMBER token as described by the lexical conventions in Grammar :

        All leading and trailing <blank> characters are discarded.

        If the first non- <blank> is '+' or '-', it is discarded.

        Each occurrence of the decimal point character from the current locale is changed to a <period>.
```

NULL will NOT be recognized as NUMBER token per the above analysis either.

So, per the above, an input field is only considered to be Numeric-String if the input value "looks like" a number which of course NULL does not so an unpopulated `$<whatever>` is just a String with value NULL and any comparison involving a String is a String-comparison (see the table at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing for IMHO the clearest depiction of comparison types) so it'll never be equal to any Number, including 0, since `$X == 0` is actually treated as `$X == "0"` which is the same as `"" == "0"` when `$X` is NULL.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177426/discussion-on-answer-by-ed-morton-in-awk-why-does-a-nonexistent-field-like-nf).